# StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider autoconfiguration not working with Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.1 and SCS Binder for Kinesis 4.0.0

Tags: spring-cloud-aws, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

After reading [the documentation](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#stswebidentitytokenfilecredentialsprovider), I feel like all I needed to do was add the `software.amazon.awssdk:sts` dependency and Spring would autoconfigure the `StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider`, but I always get the following error when writing a message to Kinesis via KPL:

```
2023-08-07 | 10:34:20.256 | kpl-daemon-0003  | WARN  | c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    | Trace:                                  | Span:                  | [2023-08-07 14:34:20.256507] [0x00000071][0x00007f379cdfa6c0] [warning] [AWS Log: ERROR](AWSXmlClient)HTTP response code: 403
Resolved remote host IP address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Exception name: InvalidClientTokenId
Error message: The security token included in the request is invalid.
4 response headers:
content-length : 306
content-type : text/xml
date : Mon, 07 Aug 2023 14:34:19 GMT
x-amzn-requestid : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2023-08-07 | 10:34:20.256 | kpl-daemon-0003  | ERROR | c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    | Trace:                                  | Span:                  | [2023-08-07 14:34:20.256566] [0x00000071][0x00007f379cdfa6c0] [error] [pipeline.h:228] Failed to get StreamARN using STS GetCallerIdentity | Code: InvalidClientTokenId | Message: The security token included in the request is invalid. | Request was: Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
2023-08-07 | 10:34:20.256 | kpl-daemon-0003  | WARN  | c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    | Trace:                                  | Span:                  | terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::system_error> >'
2023-08-07 | 10:34:20.257 | kpl-daemon-0003  | WARN  | c.a.s.k.producer.LogInputStreamReader    | Trace:                                  | Span:                  |   what():  Failed to set TLS value: Invalid argument
2023-08-07 | 10:34:21.276 | kpl-daemon-0005  | ERROR | c.a.s.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer   | Trace:                                  | Span:                  | Error in child process
java.lang.RuntimeException: EOF reached during read
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:532)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:508)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:504)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.readSome(Daemon.java:553)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.receiveMessage(Daemon.java:243)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$500(Daemon.java:61)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$3.run(Daemon.java:298)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2023-08-07 | 10:34:21.285 | -pool-1-thread-0 | ERROR | o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   | Trace:                                  | Span:                  | org.springframework.integration.aws.support.AwsRequestFailureException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[27], headers={...omitted for security purposes...
        at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.AbstractAwsMessageHandler.handleResponse(AbstractAwsMessageHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.AbstractAwsMessageHandler.lambda$handleMessageInternal$0(AbstractAwsMessageHandler.java:117)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.KplMessageHandler$2.onFailure(KplMessageHandler.java:488)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1124)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1270)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1038)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:808)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:55)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$2.run(KinesisProducer.java:200)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: EOF reached during read
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: EOF reached during read
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:532)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:508)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:504)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.readSome(Daemon.java:553)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.receiveMessage(Daemon.java:243)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$500(Daemon.java:61)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$3.run(Daemon.java:298)
        ... 3 more
```

So, it appears that this bean isn't created via autoconfiguration and that a different credential provider is. What else needs to be done to ensure the `StsWebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` is autoconfigured with the correct properties?

We have service accounts set up in EKS, and I've been able to `kubectl exec` into the container to ensure that the `AWS_ROLE_ARN` and `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` environment variables are mapped correctly.

Comment: Hi @Keith Bennett - I am also facing same issue, are you able to resolve it

Comment: No, not yet. I am hopeful that someone from the Spring community has encountered this as well and can recommend a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trials and errors, here is the solution that finally works:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducerConfiguration;
import io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.core.CredentialsProviderAutoConfiguration;
import java.util.UUID;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.AwsRegionProvider;

@AutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureAfter(CredentialsProviderAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureBefore(KinesisBinderConfiguration.class)
@Slf4j
public class KinesisProducerAutoConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.sts.role-arn}")
  private String roleArn;

  @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.sts.web-identity-token-file}")
  private String webIdentityTokenFile;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.kpl-kcl-enabled")
  public KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration(
      AwsRegionProvider awsRegionProvider) {
    log.debug("Creating KinesisProducerConfiguration...");
    var kinesisProducerConfiguration = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();
    var webIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider =
        WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.builder()
            .roleArn(roleArn)
            .roleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .webIdentityTokenFile(webIdentityTokenFile)
            .build();
    kinesisProducerConfiguration.setCredentialsProvider(webIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider);
    kinesisProducerConfiguration.setRegion(awsRegionProvider.getRegion().id());
    return kinesisProducerConfiguration;
  }
}
```

And in my `src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml` file I have the following defined:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    aws:
      credentials:
        sts:
          role-arn: ${AWS_ROLE_ARN}
          web-identity-token-file: ${AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE}
```

I learned that the default Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Kinesis implementation does not work that can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kinesis/config/KinesisBinderConfiguration.java#L229). This is because version 0.15.7 of the KPL library requires the use of STS (read more about this requirement [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer#required-kpl-update--v0150)). We are deploying our containers to EKS, and previously we set up service accounts that provide the environment variable values mapped into the yml properties in `bootstrap.yml` you can see posted in the solution. One of the odd things I noticed is that [on this line](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kinesis/config/KinesisBinderConfiguration.java#L287), you can see that the secret access key and access key id arguments are passed in the wrong order when constructing the `BasicAwsCredentials` object, but even then the solution as it's currently coded in the Kinesis binder won't work. I know this because I tried a similar adapter-style solution with the `BasicAwsCredentials` arguments passed in the correct order within the autoconfiguration class I posted in the solution.